# success function in ajax jquery is not being called with Json datatype?? it always jumps to error function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

success function in ajax jquery is not being called with Json datatype?? it always jumps to error function??pls tell me whats wrong with this code!!
//jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax({  
 type: 'GET',  
 dataType: 'json',
 async:false,
 contentType:'application/json',               data:'fname1='+$('#fname').val()+'&lname1='+$('#lname').val()+'&email1='+$('#email').val()+'&contact1='+$('#contact').val()+'&password1='+$('#password').val(), 
beforeSend: function(x){
if(x && x.overrideMimeType){                            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     }
    },
url: "./register.php",
success:function(data) {
if(data1.success=="true")
{
 $('#register_response').html("<img src='images/36.gif'  alt='Signing Up..' />");
$('#dialog').fadeOut('slow');
$('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
window.location="index.php";
 }
},
error: function(data) {
console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);                     }  
});
```

this my php code from where m accepting json data!!

//php code

```
<?php

    $fname=$_POST['fname1'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname1'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact1'];
    $email=$_POST['email1'];
    $pass=$_POST['password1'];

    require("connect.php");

    $qry="SELECT * FROM register WHERE $email='$email'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==0)
    {
        $data = array('success'=>"true");
        echo json_encode($data);
        $query="INSERT INTO register(fname,lname,contact,email,password)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$contact','$email','$pass')";
        $rslt=mysql_query($query,$con);
        setcookie("user",$email,time()+36000);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('success'=>"false");
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `$` in your query, it should be:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email'";
```

You need to add error checking so you'll see these errors:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry, $con) or die (mysql_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your return values are only true or false, you can skip using json and try using a simple jQuery.post or jQuery.get
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
var data =  'fname1=' + $('#fname').val() + '&lname1=' + $('#lname').val() + '&email1=' + $('#email').val() + '&contact1=' + $('#contact').val() + '&password1=' + $('#password').val();
jQuery.get('/register/'+data,function(response){
   if (response == "true") {
        $('#register_response').html("<img src='images/36.gif'  alt='Signing Up..' />");
        $('#dialog').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
        window.location = "index.php";
    }else{
      //handle your error
    }
});
```